# Having trouble with giving strings values (Python)

Tags: python

For School I am meant to create a program that identifies your mood and then tells you what it really is. Anyway with my code I keep getting errors about the way I have assigned values to my strings. Currently my code looks like this:

```
import random
smiles = ['XD',';)',':)',':()',':(']
history = []
reality = random.choice(smiles)

('XD')= 5
(':)') = 4
(':|') = 3
(':T') = 2
(':(') = 1

def menu():
    print (smiles)
    int(input("Which emoticon do you relate to?"))
     if 1:
         print("You are Fealing like XD")
         print("but in reality you are feeling like", reality)
     etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot assign to a string. Perhaps you want a dictionary.

Comment: @Radan python does not have a switch statement.

Comment: Ignore me then! :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you cannot assign a value to a string, you need to store them in a type of a collection, dictionary or list etc.

Given that you're asking for a number from the user, you can just assign the users input to a variable then compare that against the index in the array. Feel free to add error handling here for an input that is outside the length of the array.

```
int(input("Which emoticon do you relate to?"))
 if 1:
```

could be

```
user_input = int(input("Which emoticon do you relate to?"))
if user_input - 1 == 0:  # -1 since lists are 0 indexed.
```

You could make this generic as well and remove the if statement and just use

```
users_smile = smiles[user_input - 1]
print("You are Fealing like {}".format(users_smile))
```

Comment: Subtract the `1` once - you don't want to be doing that for each `if/elif` - also - might want to check bounds

Comment: @JonClements - Yes I agree, was trying not to change too many things at once in this code :) (also noted for the OP to add error handling)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value to string as @juanpa.arrivillaga said so you should use dictionary

```
smiles_dict = { 5: 'XD', 4: ':)', 3: ':|', 2: ':T', 1: ':(' }
```

and then use

```
smiles_dict.get(reality)
```

hope this might help you